# Are these tags on reopening and closing duplicates?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Are the tags: [reopen-request](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request), [close-reasons](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [closing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closing), [reopening](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopening) duplicates? Ought some be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** as they are not duplicates:

- [reopen-request](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request) is for a post that specifically asks for the Community to consider voting to reopen a post.
- [close-reasons](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons) is when OP is asking the Community to discuss on the possible reasons a question was closed. This is independent from a request to reopen, and should be more focused on the reasons *why* it was closed, as to improve on future posts.
- [closing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closing) is about the process of closing itself, as well is [reopening](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopening) for the process of reopening a post.

Perhaps you have seen them mixed up sometimes, and thus your confusion. But all users should be aware of these differences to tag accordingly.